# why does my box-shadow not work in an image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a code that makes images but when I put a box shadow the image does not show a shadow
but if I box shadow the 1st container then the other images get the shadow on them.
if do an image on the 2nd container then the image will be a box instead of following the outside of image when the images go down

```css
.imgcont{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .imgcont img {box-shadow:0px 2px 10px black ;
        width: 400px;
        max-height: 400px;
        margin: -50% 0 0 -50%;
    }
    .imageconcon{
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div id="alith">
<h2> alith.io (unfinnished)</h1>

    <h3>images</h3>
    <div class="imageconcon">
    <div class="imgcont">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554050857-c84a8abdb5e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"></div>
    <div class="imgcont">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554050857-c84a8abdb5e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"></div>
        <div class="imgcont">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554050857-c84a8abdb5e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"></div>
            <!--- the img is ment to be black-->
```

for some reason, it works on everything BUT images,
any help would be appreciated

Comment: @NarenMurali i dont know how to use it

Comment: Instead of using an external site like jsfiddle please put a runnable snippet into your question using the SO <> facility. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are tring to add shadow for images which are in a div. but the parent div's overflow is hidden.
you need to add shadow to the parent div and not for the images:

```css
.imgcont{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px #000000; 
box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px #000000;
    }
    .imgcont img {
      
        width: 400px;
        max-height: 400px;
        margin: -50% 0 0 -50%;
    }
    .imageconcon{
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div id="alith">
<h2> alith.io (unfinnished)</h1>

    <h3>images</h3>
    <div class="imageconcon">
    <div class="imgcont">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554050857-c84a8abdb5e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"></div>
    <div class="imgcont">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554050857-c84a8abdb5e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"></div>
        <div class="imgcont">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554050857-c84a8abdb5e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"></div>
```

Comment: Or add shadow to the parent of parent and add a width for it

Comment: but then the img's shadow overlaps other images (in my thing the images aren't black)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to add shadow to the container:

```css
img {
      width: 400px;
      max-height: 400px; 
    }
    .imageconcon{
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px #000000;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px #000000;
      width:fit-content;
    }
```

```html
<div id="alith">
    <h2> alith.io (unfinnished)</h1>
      <h3>images</h3>
      <div class="imageconcon">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
      </div>
```